# How to load mapbox without adding it to view hierarchy?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

What I do is:

have some `Card` objects. Every card is represented on a map with some anotations and polygon and additional elements. A whole card looks like this:

[image]

This is a simple uiview with mapbox view and other subviews. All I do is to take a snapshot of card view and all its subviews like this (`extension UIView`):

```
var snapshot: UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

This is fine, I can simply get inside card view controller, load everything, tap done and save new image for card.

But now I need to iterate over all cards and refresh all images... but the map to be displayed must be on the screen or in view hierarchy. Is there a way to load somehow the mapbox map and take a screenshot again for every card?

I have tried to do this with view from `.xib` but the map is not loaded. So the screenshot is without rendered map.

You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [offline sdk](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/offline-pack/) for that.

Comment: No, it it not what I need to implement;( but thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could move the map without animation with:

```
mapView.setCenter(newPosition, zoomLevel: zoomLevel, direction: 0.0, animated: false, completionHandler: {
  //Take screenshot
  //Move to the next screenshot or end loop
})
```

and cover the map with an opaque view that is in style with your app until the screenshots are taken. For example you could show a white view with a progress bar in it, but it depends on your app style.

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS 3.7.0+ includes [`MGLMapSnapshotter`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Classes/MGLMapSnapshotter.html), which will get you a rasterized map without a map view — see [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/map-snapshotter/) for a basic implementation.

If you need to add annotations or shape overlays, our [MapboxStatic.swift](https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxStatic.swift/) library is probably a better fit.

Comment: The point is that BEFORE I do a snapshot I need to add some annotations, draw polygon and call `showAnnotations()`... and then I could do a snapshot. Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, using annotations/overlays with `MGLMapSnapshotter` isn’t very easy right now. For that use case, you may want to look at our [MapboxStatic.swift](https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxStatic.swift/) library, which offers configurable overlays.